# Error: THREE.GLTFLoader: Unsupported asset. glTF versions >=2.0 are supported

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d-modelling

While using three.js I got this error when parsing from the GLTF JSON file, It is exported from the three.js 3D viewer and editor and it shows that it has a version of 4.5 in the JSON file

**This is the code in the JSX file**

```
import { GLTFLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader";

// Spaceships
import Praetor from "../Assets/GameObjects/Spaceships/Praetor.json";

const SpaceshipLoader = new GLTFLoader();

class Spaceship {
  constructor() {
    this.health = 100;
    this.speed = 10;
    this.positionX = 0;
    this.positionY = 0;
  }
  create(Scene) {
    // Loading the spaceship itself into a scene which is taken as a parameter
    SpaceshipLoader.parse(
      Praetor,
      function (SpaceshipObject) {
        Scene.add(SpaceshipObject);
      },
      // Function to display the loading progress of the object in the scene
      function (xhr) {
        console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + "% loaded");
      },
      // Function to display an error message if it occured while loading the object
      function (error) {
        console.log("An error happened");
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
  move() {}
  shoot() {}
}

export { Spaceship };
```

**And this is some the data from the JSON file, excluding the Array buffers**

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "version": "4.5",
    "type": "Object",
    "generator": "Object3D.toJSON"
  },
  "geometries": [
    {
      "uuid": "d6edee71-c106-4e47-b6eb-4fed31adf432",
      "type": "BufferGeometry",
      "data": {
        "attributes": {
          "position": {
            "isInterleavedBufferAttribute": true,
            "itemSize": 3,
            "data": "b443ef6f-e5e3-4350-9ef6-c45065b45033",
            "offset": 0,
            "normalized": false
          },
          "normal": {
            "isInterleavedBufferAttribute": true,
            "itemSize": 3,
            "data": "b443ef6f-e5e3-4350-9ef6-c45065b45033",
            "offset": 3,
            "normalized": false
          },
          "uv": {
            "isInterleavedBufferAttribute": true,
            "itemSize": 2,
            "data": "b443ef6f-e5e3-4350-9ef6-c45065b45033",
            "offset": 6,
            "normalized": false
          }
        },
        "index": {
          "type": "Uint16Array",
          "array": [
            0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 6, 9, 10, 6, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
            18, 19, 20, 21, 19, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 27, 30, 31, 32,
            33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 35, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 40, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47
          ]
        },
        "interleavedBuffers": {
          "b443ef6f-e5e3-4350-9ef6-c45065b45033": {
            "uuid": "b443ef6f-e5e3-4350-9ef6-c45065b45033",
            "buffer": "53392d6c-081d-44a5-ace0-badffbc81707",
            "type": "Float32Array",
            "stride": 8
          }
        },
```

**Also note that it the object was loading perfectly in the three.js editor**

Answer (score 0):

You have not exported a glTF asset from the `three.js` editor. It's the `three.js` specific JSON format which can only be loaded with [THREE.ObjectLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/loaders/ObjectLoader).

In the editor, make sure to use the menu entry `File > Export GLB` or `File > Export GLTF` to create a glTF asset.

> Also note that it the object was loading perfectly in the three.js editor

The editor can automatically detect the correct loader for this JSON.

Comment: It still does not work, it gives the following error 
```url.lastIndexOf is not a function at LoaderUtils.extractUrlBase```